# How can we write a function List multiPop(int k) that pops k elements from the stack or until the stack is empty?

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to write a method that pops k elements from the stack. Any help would be appreciated.

```
This is what I have tried: 
    public void multipop(int k) { 
    List l = nil(); 
    while (true) {
    for(int i =0; i < k; i++) { 
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried just popping `k` elements, stopping early if the stack becomes empty?

Comment: I have been learning java for few months. I can understand the theory but find it hard to implement it. I have studied loops, arrays, stacks etc.

Comment: The main issue with what you've tried is: how are you breaking out of the loop? Your loop condition should probably hold relevant logic.

Answer (score 1):

Translate the following concept in to Java:

```
create a list to store the popped members in.
while (the stack is not empty and we have to pop more elements) {
    add a popped member from the stack to the list
}
return the list.
```

Done

Comment: Thanks, How is this so far? 
public void multipop(int k) {
  List l = nil();
  while (true) {
   for(int i =0; i < k; i++) { } @rolfl

Comment: There's a number of problems with that, but adding code in your comments is not the right way to do it. Edit your original question with an Update, and that will make it easier to format right.

Answer (score 0):

```
list multipop(int k, list stack){

   int increment = 0;
   while(stack.next() != null && k < increment){ 
      stack.pop();
      increment++;
   }
}
return stack;
```

I'm sorting assuming you have the methods .next() and .pop() already created.

Comment: No, I don't have method .next() and .pop(). How would I go about creating them?
@progenhard

Comment: post the code you have for your list class already or are you using a standard list<> class from java?

Comment: for some reason it won't let me post the code. Says its too long. Would I be able to email you or inbox?